# VSCode - XDebug loads then is not loaded

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xdebug

I am trying to use XDebug with PHP and VS Code on Windows.  I have successfully installed XDebug because it shows up in the phpinfo() page.

When I attempt to use XDebug on VS Code, I get this error:

```
DEBUG     Checking PHPLS_ALLOW_XDEBUG

DEBUG     The xdebug extension is loaded (2.7.1)

DEBUG     Process restarting (PHPLS_ALLOW_XDEBUG=internal|2.7.1|0|*|*)
DEBUG     Running C:\Users\***\Documents\Applications\php-7.3.4-nts-Win32-VC15-x64\php.exe -n -c C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Temp\AF9E.tmp c:\Users\***\.vscode\extensions\felixfbecker.php-intellisense-2.3.10\vendor\felixfbecker\language-server\bin\php-language-server.php --tcp=127.0.0.1:50124 --memory-limit=4095M

DEBUG     Checking PHPLS_ALLOW_XDEBUG

DEBUG     Restarted (64 ms). The xdebug extension is not loaded

[Info  - 11:04:12 AM] 1 files total
[Info  - 11:04:12 AM] Indexing project for definitions and static references
Parsing file:///c:/xampp/htdocs/blank/blank.php
[Info  - 11:04:12 AM] Indexing project for dynamic references
[Info  - 11:04:12 AM] 0 Packages
[Info  - 11:04:12 AM] All 1 PHP files parsed in 0 seconds. 148 MiB allocated.
```

Comment: Wild guess: you may have more than one PHP installation on your system ... which then use own/different php.ini (by default it's taken from the same folder where PHP executable is located). Therefore it's possible that php.ini used by `C:\Users\***\Documents\Applications\php-7.3.4-nts-Win32-VC15-x64\php.exe` does not have Xdebug installed. (BTW: why such weird path (which suggests that it comes with some another software).. why not install PHP manually once properly and use it?)

Comment: I do have multiple installations each with XDebug installed verified through phpinfo.  I have PHP installed through XAMPP and downloaded through PHP's website.  I downloaded PHP from PHP's website because on https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/php it says "Tip: Using XAMPP? Install the full version of PHP in order to obtain the development libraries."  Do you think I should just delete the PHP from PHP's website?

Comment: My main point was: try using the same PHP installation .. because first it check and finds Xdebug loaded (as per your log) and then it must be executing some another PHP .. where Xdebug is not present... So check what PHP it uses and point all to the same location (sorry, not a VSCode user here so cannot give you more precise instructions on what can be changed and where)

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue too and looking at the configuration that was being provided (in the original example above it's `C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Temp\AF9E.tmp`), I found that the zend_extension line had been commented out.

ie. it appears as this in the .tmp file:

> ;zend_extension=php_xdebug-2.7.2-7.3-vc15-nts-x86_64.dll

The semicolon being the commenting character.

A little experimentation showed that it was commenting it out itself based on the filename.  I renamed the DLL to `totallynotphpdebgr272.dll` and set that as the zend_extension in php.ini.  After that change it no longer commented that line in the generated .tmp file and I was able to start debugging php successfully in vscode.